# Use opencv in python idle

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I installed opencv in python3 using pip. It runs well in terminal, but when I try to run it in idle, it cannot import cv2. What could be the solution?
I am using vim as my python idle.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue of having multiple python versions on your machine, you should select the python interpreter that is global to your system "that which utilises" pip in terminal.